# Comunication between a service and a broadcastreceiver by handlers

Tags: android, service, background, broadcastreceiver, handler

My app works like that: I have an activity with a broadcastreceiver as inner class (that could actually be moved in its own class) and a remote service (that works in its own thread). The activity sets up all the variables and starts all the processes. The service use the proximityAlerts to track my moves and triggers the broadcastreceiver when I'm inside a specific place. Now the problem is that after the broadcastreciever is done I need to call back the service to clean up everything and to call stopSelf(). Given that the activity could be no longer in foreground, I need a way to call the Service using handlers from the broadcastreceiver that's in background. I'll show you the code then I tell you what's the error that I get:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static MainActivity instance; 

    static Messenger messenger;
    static boolean serviceBind;

    private static ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            messenger = new Messenger(binder);
            serviceBind = true;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            messenger = null;
            serviceBind = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        instance = this;        

        MyVariable mv = new MyVariable();
        addProximityAlert(mv);
    }

    protected static class ResponseHandler extends Handler {
        Boolean result;

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            int respCode = msg.what;

            switch(respCode) {
                case ProximityService.ADD_PROXIMITY_ALERT_RESPONSE: {
                    result = msg.getData().getBoolean("respData");
                }
                case ProximityService.REMOVE_PROXIMITY_ALERT_RESPONSE: {
                    result = msg.getData().getBoolean("respData");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void startService() {
        Intent i = new Intent (this, ProximityService.class);
        startService(i);
        bindService(i, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public void addNewProximityAlert(MyVariable mv) {
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, ProximityService.ADD_PROXIMITY_ALERT);
        msg.replyTo = new Messenger(new ResponseHandler());
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelable("data", mv);
        msg.setData(b);
        try {
            messenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void removeProximityAlert(MyVariable mv) {   
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, ProximityService.REMOVE_PROXIMITY_ALERT);
        msg.replyTo = new Messenger(new ResponseHandler());
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelable("data", mv);
        msg.setData(b);
        try {
            messenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

            Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, true);

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            bundle.setClassLoader(context.getClassLoader());
            MyVariable mv = bundle.getParcelable("com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver.mv");

            if (entering) {
            // do stuff 
            } else {
                // do stuff 
            };   
            MainActivity ssm = MainActivity.instance;
            ssm.removeProximityAlert(mv);   
        }

        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Intent intent= new Intent(this, ProximityService.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            serviceBind=true;
        }

        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if(serviceBind) {
                serviceBind = false;
                unbindService(mConnection);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
            if(serviceBind) {
                serviceBind = false;
                unbindService(mConnection);
            }
        }
```

ProximityService:

```
public class ProximityService extends Service {

static final long POINT_RADIUS = 250; // in Meters
    static final long PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION = -1;

    static final int ADD_PROXIMITY_ALERT = 2;
    static final int ADD_PROXIMITY_ALERT_RESPONSE = 3;
    static final int REMOVE_PROXIMITY_ALERT = 4;
    static final int REMOVE_PROXIMITY_ALERT_RESPONSE = 5;

    public static final String RESULT = "result";

    int minDistance = 50; // 50 metri
    int minTime = 1000*5*1; // 5 Secondi

    private MyLocationListener myLocationListener;

    private Messenger msg = new Messenger(new MyHandler());
    private static boolean isRunning = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return msg.getBinder();
    }

    class MyHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            int msgType = msg.what;

            switch(msgType) {
            case ADD_PROXIMITY_ALERT: {
                try {
                    final Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                    bundle.setClassLoader(getClassLoader());
                    MyVariable mv = bundle.getParcelable("data");
                    addProximityAlert(getApplicationContext(), mv);

                    Message resp = Message.obtain(null, ADD_PROXIMITY_ALERT_RESPONSE);
                    Bundle bResp = new Bundle();
                    bResp.putBoolean("respData", true);
                    resp.setData(bResp);
                    msg.replyTo.send(resp);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            case REMOVE_PROXIMITY_ALERT: {
                try {
                    final Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                    bundle.setClassLoader(getClassLoader());
                    MyVariable mv = bundle.getParcelable("data");
                    removeProximityAlert(mv);

                    Message resp = Message.obtain(null, REMOVE_PROXIMITY_ALERT_RESPONSE);
                    Bundle bResp = new Bundle();
                    bResp.putBoolean("respData", true);
                    resp.setData(bResp);

                    msg.replyTo.send(resp);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

     @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  
        myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();      
        return(START_REDELIVER_INTENT);
    }

    public static boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public void addProximityAlert(Context context, MyVariable mv) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(getProvider(), minTime, minDistance, myLocationListener);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver.mv", mv);

        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        locationManager.addProximityAlert(mv.getLocation().getLatitude(), mv.getLocation().getLongitude(), POINT_RADIUS, PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, proximityIntent);
    }

    public void removeProximityAlert(MyVariable mv) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        locationManager.removeProximityAlert(proximityIntent);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
        myLocationListener = null;
        locationManager = null;
        stopSelf();
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //do stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

So everything works fine but when it has to execute ssm.removeProximityAlert(mv) I get a NullPointerException error because messenger at the end of removeProximityAlert is null. I know why I get that error but I have no idea how to fix it. How could I do? Of course if you find something else not working or badly done I'd be glad to hear advices and suggestions. 
The code shown here is actually a semplification of my code just to shrink it a bit and cut out useless stuff.

Comment: what do yo need that broadcast receiver for?

Comment: It gets called when I enter the position of the proximityAlert. The broadcast itself just send a notification of entering or exiting, nothing more

Comment: so remove it if its useless, create the notification in your service

Comment: it's not useless trust me. this code is way shorter than the original one cause I can't post 1500 lines here. The problem is not that one. I'm sure you can call a method of a class even if that one is in background but I don't know how

Comment: maybe but i see control flow too complex (that BroadcastReceiver smells for a mile), also instead of two way Messengers did you consider using simple AIDL api?

Comment: I read that for simple situation like mine it was better to use messengers instead of AIDL. Do you think it would be better to use AIDL instead?

Comment: aidl gives you "like" direct method invocation,  so the api is simple,  but if you never used it before you can stay with Messengers,  its up to you

Comment: SO it will allow me to use every method of every class even if they are not in foreground? Cause my problem is that I can't use the messenger cause the activity is not in foreground and it could actually have been killed. So every initialization of the variables of that class should be done again before using messenger to comunicate with the service. If you have a good and easy guide on how to set up and use the AIDL please share the link here

Comment: this is what i don't understand at all,  if you need to do some ui related job do it when activity is bound to your service (onServiceConnected been called) , when your service needs to notify something and no activity is present use std Notifications to inform the user about that

Comment: Yeah you are right. The thing is that the broadcastreceiver gets called, then sends the notification, then it has to call back the service to clean up the database entry (cause MyVariable is stored in a database) and call stopSelf(). So after I send the notification from the broadcastreceiver I have to call the method that does that in the service. But since I'm no more connected with it cause the MainActivity (where the broadcastreceiver is) is no more in foreground I don't know how. In other words is there a way to connect somehow the broadcastreceiver to the service? AIDL will do the work?

Comment: Fron BroadcastReceiver you can only startService, bindService is not allowed

Comment: I figured it. that's why I try to call the method that I have in MainActivity to do it. But of course it can't cause since it's not in foreground none of its variable is initialized; like messenger for example

Comment: that's why i said in the beginning that this BroadcastReceiver smells, if it's called only by your service then it's a bad design

Comment: ah yeah? but it's required by the proximityAlert that triggers a broadcastreceiver when you enter the spot you set it for

Comment: when using `LocationManager.addProximityAlert` you need to pass a  `PendingIntent` which may point to an **Activity** or **Service** or **BroadcastReceiver**, so you are not limited to `BroadcastReceiver` only

Comment: But if I send it to an activity the activity gets resumed and goes to the foreground or I can use its methods without having it in foreground?

Comment: I've found a way to do it. Maybe it's not the best way but at least for now it works. Then I try to use aidl and see if I can do it better or in the proper way. The solution I've found to comunicate between the BoradcastRecevier and the Service is just to call startService with MyVariable inside the intent and catch it on the onStartCommand in the service calling then the method I need on that variable

Comment: Remove brosdcast receiver use just service in pendingintent

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the activity you have to always populate the replyTo when you create a message that gets a reply.

This would mask the error in the service.

```
if (msg.replyTo !=null) { 
  msg.replyTo.send(Message.obtain(null, REMOVE_ALERT));
}
```

This would fix the error make a routine to create new messages that populates the replyto field with the client messenger.

```
private static Message getMsg(int msgWhat) {
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, msgWhat);
    // only set reply to on the register command
    msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
    msg.what = msgWhat;
    return msg;
}
```

Other considerations on your code.

Consider using arg1 and arg2 to pass simple data.  arg1=1 for true arg1 = 0 for false this would be more efficient than populating a bundle to pass a boolean.

Consider the app has 10 seconds in a BroadcastReceiver before an ANR fires so you shouldn't //doStuff.  The broadcast receiver is used to do simple instantaneous things like toggle visibility, start a service, start an asynctask.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

for the activity or fragment.  Your implementation may be different.

The sample below only expects replies on the register or unregister messages sent to the service.  The service saves the handler (replyTo) and sends messages when it records a location.    This is the code I use in myapp BestRides.  This is part of a client class that fragments and activities use to connect to a service that records locations.  The code I built this from was on developer.android.com but I couldn't find it today.

```
public ClientServiceLocationRecorder(WeakReference<Context> weakContext,
                                     WeakReference<LocationRecorderClientCallback> weakCallback) {
    ClientServiceLocationRecorder.weakContext = weakContext;
    ClientServiceLocationRecorder.weakCallbacks.add(weakCallback);

    //start of the service its import to start and bind so the service
    //stays up when the activity finishes.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Context context = ClientServiceLocationRecorder.weakContext.get();
            context.startService(new Intent(context, ServiceLocationRecorder.class));
            // bind to the service
            if (!mIsBound) {
                // Bind to the service
                context.bindService(new Intent(context,
                                ServiceLocationRecorder.class), mConnection,
                        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                mIsBound = true;
            }
            sndMessageToLocationRecorder(ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_GET_DISTANCE);
            runRecordStatus();
        }
    }).start();
}



private static ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    // Called when the connection with the service is established
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        mService = new Messenger(service);
        // We want to monitor the service for as long as we are
        // connected to it.
        sendMsg(getMsg(ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT));
    }

    // Called when the connection with the service disconnects unexpectedly
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mService = null;
    }
};

private static void sendMsg(Message msg) {
    if (isRegistered || msg.replyTo != null) {
        try {
            mService.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // In this case the service has crashed before we could even
            // do anything with it; we can count on soon being
            // disconnected (and then reconnected if it can be restarted)
            // so there is no need to do anything here.
        }
    } else {
        // queue the messages until we are registered
        // msgQueue is arrayList<Message>
        msgQueue.add(msg);
    }
}

    private static Message getMsg(int locationRecorderMsg) {
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, locationRecorderMsg);
    // only set reply to on the register command
    msg.replyTo = ((locationRecorderMsg == ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT
            || locationRecorderMsg == ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_UNREGISTER_CLIENT)
            ? mMessenger
            : null);
    msg.what = locationRecorderMsg;
    return msg;
}


final static Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

private static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {

    Bundle data;

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            //always have most used switch at the top for efficiency
            case ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_LOCATION:
                data = msg.getData();
                lat = data.getDouble(ServiceLocationRecorder.BUNDLE_LATITUDE);
                lon = data.getDouble(ServiceLocationRecorder.BUNDLE_LONGITUDE);
                distance = data
                        .getDouble(ServiceLocationRecorder.BUNDLE_TRACKED_DISTANCE);
                startMillis = data
                        .getLong(ServiceLocationRecorder.BUNDLE_START_MILLIS);
                endMillis = data
                        .getLong(ServiceLocationRecorder.BUNDLE_END_MILLIS);
                numberOfLocations = msg.arg1;
                sendLocationMessageToClient();
                break;
            // THESE ARE JUST SIMPLE MESSAGES
            case ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT:
                // send queued messages once registered.
                if (!isRegistered) {
                    isRegistered = true;
                    for (Message qMsg : msgQueue) {
                        sendMsg(qMsg);
                    }
                    msgQueue.clear();
                }
                break;
            case ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_PICTURE:
                // TODO NOT IMPLEMENTED
                // call the client function
                // not implemented.
                break;
            case ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_GET_DISTANCE:
                data = msg.getData();
                distance = data
                        .getDouble(ServiceLocationRecorder.BUNDLE_TRACKED_DISTANCE);
                startMillis = data
                        .getLong(ServiceLocationRecorder.BUNDLE_START_MILLIS);
                endMillis = data
                        .getLong(ServiceLocationRecorder.BUNDLE_END_MILLIS);
                numberOfLocations = msg.arg1;
                sendDistanceMessageToClient();
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}

// interact with the above code send a message to the service.  
public void sndMessageToLocationRecorder(int locationRecorderMsg) {
    switch (locationRecorderMsg) {
        case ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_RECORD_START:
            runStartRecording();
            break;
        case ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_RECORD_STOP:
            runStopRecording();
            break;
        case ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_CLEAR:
            ClientServiceLocationRecorder.distance = 0;
            ClientServiceLocationRecorder.startMillis = 0;
            sendMsg(getMsg(ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_CLEAR));
            break;
        case ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_RECORD_STATUS:
            runRecordStatus();
            break;
        case ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_GET_DISTANCE:
            sendMsg(getMsg(ServiceLocationRecorder.MSG_GET_DISTANCE));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it but the proble is that Messenger messenger is null not the Message msg. The error that I get it's only when I call the method of MainActivity from the bradcastreceiver. The service looks working fine. the "do stuff" thing is actually just pop up a notification, nothing more. You suggest me to do it elsewhere? Thanks for the arg1/arg2 thing, I will change it

Comment: Your Welcome.  Popup is ok just commit to memory seconds on broadcast receiver before ANR.  ehhhhh I can see in your code your not populating the replyTo when you obtain a new message.  It's important to do this and a structured approach of obtaining a new message with a getMsg function is the way to go.  Also one final note when your done with a message you have to recycle it.

Comment: ok i will. but about the messenger problem? cause that doesn't get initialized since MainActivity is not in foreground. I can't create a method to initialize it cause it's part of ServiceConnection mConnection and there is where I get the IBinder from the service. I really have no idea how to do it. Maybe the AIDL option as pskink would do the job. I've never used it so I don't know what you can do with that

Comment: I put all my relevant client code up.  My implementation only gets replies on msg.what = register.  The service saves the replyTo when it receives a msg.what = register messages and sends messages every time a location is recorded so I can display it on the map.  Checkout the app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gosylvester.bestrides to see it in action run the route recorder the locations are recorded in the background service and displayed on the map in real time.  Or you can exit the app and service stays up recording the locations.

Comment: oh perfect. do you have the code on github or similar so that I can check it out? I'm pretty new to Android and seeing the whole code would let me understand it better I guess